# Failed to stop TeamCity build agent service via net.exe. Failed to start process. Return code was 2 not equal to zero.

Tags: teamcity

I installed TeamCity locally on my Windows 8 machine. When I open TeamCity via my browser it shows 0 agents. When I look at the agents, I see 1 agent disconnected with a message that it unregistered itself and the message "will update".

I wait but nothing happens.

I checked the log file in `C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\logs\teamcity-agent.log` and saw that message "Upgrade call received from the build server".

I then checked `upgrade.log` in the same log folder, and saw the message `Failed to stop TeamCity build agent service via net.exe`

I had installed the TeamCity service and build agent using a user account (aka not SYSTEM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to grant permissions to manage that service to the account the services are running as. You can find a detailed walkthrough on Thom's HeadSpace blog at:

http://thommck.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/how-to-allow-non-admins-to-start-and-stop-system-services/

I'll put the summarize notes here, but you should really checkout his blog post for detailed steps and screenshots, makes it much easier.

You short of it that you create a Security Template.

1. Start the Microsoft Management Console
2. Add the Security Configuration and Analysis snap in
3. Add the Security Templates snap in
4. Add a new "New Template Search Path" (e.g. c:\SecurityTemplates)
5. Create a "New Template"
6. Import your .inf file
7. Analyze Computer...
8. Select the service in question
9. Define this policy in the database
10. Edit Security...
11. Configure Computer...